# spinner de Bootstrap dentro de input submit

Tags: css, bootstrap

¿Cómo agrego el spinner dentro del input submit?

Lo que quiero es ubicarlo a lado izquierdo del texto, pensé que era algo sencillo, pero llevo un buen rato dándole vueltas (literalmente jajaja) y no logro incluirlo.

La función del submit es enviar los datos de inicio de sesión de un simple formulari de login.

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  background: #d81921;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Ingresar"><span class="spinner-border" role="status"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo usando `position: absolute;` asi:

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  background: #d81921;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

span.spinner-border {
  position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 260px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Ingresar"><span class="spinner-border" role="status"></span>
```

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda